# Why the video memory takes too much when I replace FC layers with FCN in vgg11 as a classifier?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I just replaced FC layers with FCN in vgg11 as a classifier. But I don't know why the video memory takes too much using FCN than original FC layers. When I use original FC layers as a classifier, I can adjust batchsize to 32, it works well. Now, pycharm will give an error "cuda out of memory", I just change batchsize to 8 in using FCN.
Say, nn.Linear(512 * 7 * 7, 4096) converts to nn.Conv2d(512, 4096, (7,7)), I queried the video memory using the command nvidia-smi respectivtely when defining a rand tensor 10 * 512 * 7 * 7.
Here is my codes.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

flag1 = False
if flag1:
    tensor1 = torch.randn(10, 512, 7, 7)
    tensor1 = tensor1.cuda()
    conv2d = nn.Conv2d(512, 4096, (7, 7))
    conv2d = conv2d.cuda()
    output1 = conv2d(tensor1)

flag2 = True
if flag2:
    tensor2 = torch.randn(10, 512, 7, 7)
    tensor2 = tensor2.cuda()
    linear = nn.Linear(512 * 7 * 7, 4096)
    linear = linear.cuda()
    output2 = linear(tensor2.view(10, -1))

print("end")
```

Here is the output of video merrory.

[orginal video memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l61KN.png)

[video memory using FCN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJAvf.png)

[video memory using FC layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX4r3.png)

Since they have same prameters, why the video memory usage is so different? Looks like FC layers is better than FCN. I don't understand.

Comment: Same number of parameters != same memory usage. 7x7 conv is HUGE when you have that many channels!

Comment: Got it, thanks. Now I decide to try to replace 7*7 conv layer with 3 conv kernels of 3*3.